# microk8s.kubectl: command not found - on Ansible

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, redhat, microk8s

I'm facing issues running microk8s commands on Red Hat 8 using Ansible. I've automated the Red Hat installation process using Packer and Ansible, but when I try to run any cmd or shell related to microk8s, I encounter an error. Does anyone have a solution or suggestion for how to run microk8s commands on Red Hat 8 using Ansible?

> fatal: [10.33.52.30]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "sudo
> microk8s.kubectl config > ~/.kube/config", "delta": "0:00:00.022908",
> "end": "2023-04-20 12:57:23.943271", "msg": "non-zero return code",
> "rc": 1, "start": "2023-04-20 12:57:23.920363", "stderr": "sudo:
> microk8s.kubectl: command not found", "stderr_lines": ["sudo:
> microk8s.kubectl: command not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines":
> []}

and

> fatal: [10.33.52.30]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "microk8s
> config > /home/sys0/.kube/config", "delta": "0:00:00.004438", "end":
> "2023-04-20 12:46:50.259764", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc":
> 127, "start": "2023-04-20 12:46:50.255326", "stderr": "/bin/sh:
> microk8s: command not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: microk8s:
> command not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

Does anybody know the solution to the above issue?

Comment: I suspect microk8s initialization/patch/setting is in your .bashrc or alike init file. These are not read by ansible by default. If I'm right, you'll have to source that before each command => `shell: source ~/.bashrc && your_microk8s_rcommand`.

Comment: they're distributed as part of snap, and thus are in the `/snap/something-something/bin` path pointing to the currently installed snap version. In the future, `command -v microk8s` will show the full path to any such command in a portable way. Unlike Zeitounator's suggestion, you may be much happier setting `environment: { PATH: /snap/bin:/bin:...etcetc }` in your playbook to avoid having to copy-paste that `source` over and over

Comment: it did work thanks to you both

Comment: @shipson, Write Answer! Could you please elaborate on the solution how it was resolved write down all the steps   so that it would helps to other who are just beginner get the similar issue.

Comment: source ~/.bashrc && microk8s status --wait-ready. but before running this command with ansible im logging out and log in. and im using become_user: root to run above mentioned shell command